# How to set ui.chartType to null in Google charts for controls?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts with chart range filter controls. The control comes with a default chart (modifiable by changing ui.chartType). I would like to remove the default chart. I am looking for something like ui.chartType = None to set in the options of control chart. It just gives an error.

```
var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'chartRangeFilter_control_div1',

      'options': {
        'filterColumnIndex': 0,


'ui': {
          'chartType': 'LineChart',
          'chartOptions': {
            'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
            'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
          },
          // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the stock.
          // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
          'chartView': {
            'columns': [0, 3]
          },
          // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
          'minRangeSize': 86400000
        }
      },
      'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2012, 1, 9), 'end': new Date(2012, 2, 20)}}
    });
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the `setOption` method

```
control.setOption('ui.chartType', null);
```

however, I would think some type of chart would be required...

Comment: No luck so far.

Comment: what specifically happens using the above method? do you receive an error?

Comment: I replaced linechart with null. No change.